# Java equivalent decoding for ObjectiveC

Tags: java, objective-c

I have a requirement to porting java code to objective. But I got stuck at the decoding mechanism used in Java. Due to the wrong decoding used in ObjectiveC, my final out is going wrong from Java code. Following is the java code, which I got stuck:

```
String s = values.getProperty("s");
byte[] salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode(s);
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println("Salt DECODED = " + salt);
System.out.println("Decoded value as string " + new String(salt));
```

The output of above code follows

```
's' holds the string value "ZB3NNxAMNB/x6JpAryCd0g==",
'salt' holds the value "Salt DECODED = [B@180bc464",
'salt' hold the string value "Decoded value as string d�7"
```

When the same I written in objectiveC, I have used the following code

```
NSString *s = parsedMessageDict[@"s"]; //ZB3NNxAMNB/x6JpAryCd0g==
NSData *salt = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:s options:0];
```

The difference is that in Java salt is given as byte[] and in objectiveC, which is declared as NSData. Does this make any issue as going forward. Henceforth, all the data is processing based on the value. So I am doing wrong here itself, definitely, the final output will be wrong.

In objectiveC, should I decode the salt as string and convert to byte array or the NSData has to be converted to byte array?

Can anyone give suggestion?

Comment: When you print `[B@...` this has nothing to do with the values in the byte[], it's just saying you have a byte[] and it was give this hashCode which will be random every time you run it.  There would be no sane reason to attempt to reproduce this.

Comment: An NSData *is* a "byte array" in ObjC. That seems to be the correct form.

Comment: @BenZotto Is there any difference b/w nsdata and byte array.

Comment: Too much to write in comment, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

An `NSData` instance wraps a buffer of bytes, and allows you to manipulate it. It is the ObjC equivalent of a Java byte array. Getting the bytes from a base-64 encoded string as you're doing here is perfectly reasonable and results in an `NSData` instance. (*The second and third log lines you are printing out aren't meaningful so you shouldn't look at them to check for any kind of equivalency*.)

Since you're doing crypto here, it sort of depends on what you want to do next that determines what you do with the NSData you now have. It is true that there is a more C-native representation of a bunch of bytes (like a `unit8_t *`) that C-style crypto APIs will want. `NSData` can give you that if you call its `-bytes` method.